# Position of point with respect to hyperbola

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I know we can find position of point with respect to hyperbola using put the coordinate of point to formula of hyperbola . If the answer is negative then it's outside and if positive then it's inside . Why this is true ?

Comment: Quadratic forms are continuous functions and a hyperbola is given by the set of zeroes of a quadratic form $Q(x,y)$. If you cross a branch of a hyperbola, $Q(x,y)$ changes its sign.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Are you referring to the combined equation $ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c=0$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can you explain more ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let hyperbola be $S\equiv\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$. Let $P(x,y_1)$ be outside the hyperbola and $Q(x,y_2)$ be on the hyperbola. Then, $y_1^2>y_2^2$ (verify by drawing an image!)

Now, $$y_1^2>y_2^2$$$$y_1^2>(\frac{x^2}{a^2}-1)b^2$$$$\frac{y_1^2}{b^2}>\frac{x^2}{a^2}-1$$$$0>\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y_1^2}{b^2}-1$$

This shows that $S_P<0$ for point P outside the hyperbola. Similarly, one can prove $S_P>0$ for point P inside the hyperbola.

Comment: Thanks , is there any way to relate this (being negative and positive number of $S_P$) to the definition of hyperbola ?

Comment: @S.H.W I used the "equation" of the hyperbola in the second step of my proof. By "definition" do you mean that good old equation $|PS_1-PS_2|=2a$ ?

Comment: Yes , I mean that equation .

Comment: @S.H.W As you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Equation), if you take that equation, square it, rearrange the terms, and transform the coordinate axes, you will eventually get the equation I used in my proof. Apart from that, I don't know of a way to use that other equation directly.